# How do I pass a parameter to a python Hadoop streaming job?

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

For a python Hadoop streaming job, how do I pass a parameter to, for example, the reducer script so that it behaves different based on the parameter being passed in?

I understand that streaming jobs are called in the format of:

hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -input  -output  -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py ...

I want to affect reducer.py.

Answer (score 18):

The argument to the command line option `-reducer` can be any command, so you can try:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input inputDirs \
    -output outputDir \
    -mapper myMapper.py \
    -reducer 'myReducer.py 1 2 3' \
    -file myMapper.py \
    -file myReducer.py
```

assuming `myReducer.py` is made executable. Disclaimer: I have not tried it, but I have passed similar complex strings to `-mapper` and `-reducer` before.

That said, have you tried the

```
-cmdenv name=value
```

option, and just have your Python reducer get its value from the environment?  It's just another way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

In your Python code,

```
import os
(...)
os.environ["PARAM_OPT"]
```

In your Hapdoop command include:

```
hadoop jar \
(...)
-cmdenv PARAM_OPT=value\
(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `-reducer` as the below command

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar \
-mapper 'count_mapper.py arg1 arg2' -file count_mapper.py \
-reducer 'count_reducer.py arg3' -file count_reducer.py \
```

you can revise this 
[Link](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2013-11-23)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python you may want to check out [dumbo](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo) which provides a nice wrapper around hadoop streaming.
In dumbo you pass parameters with -param as in :

```
dumbo start yourpython.py -hadoop <hadoop-path> -input <input> -output <output>  -param <parameter>=<value>
```

And then read it in the reducer

```
def reducer:
def __init__(self):
    self.parmeter = int(self.params["<parameter>"])
def __call__(self, key, values):
    do something interesting ...
```

You can read more in the [dumbo tutorial](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki/Short-tutorial)