# Hadoop streaming for jobs with multiple arguments

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Is it possible to configure hadoop streaming to read two or more input arguments at runtime for a job?

For example, let's say I have a script which is executed as: `my_script file1 file2`

How can I specify this in hadoop streaming?

As far as I know, I can only specify jobs which have the following execution syntax: 
`my_script "fixed_params" "input"`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked in streaming much, but I'm pretty sure you can just add another `-input` argument.

Also see: [Using multiple mapper inputs in one streaming job on hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180791/using-multiple-mapper-inputs-in-one-streaming-job-on-hadoop)

Comment: I don't think so (i have already tried it, and it failed)... My understanding is that -input is used to only specify the input-arg. Specifying multiple -input args mean the streaming job will consider those multiple input-directories and/or files for the mappers but not like the syntax I specified in my qs. The whole idea of streaming, I think, is based on piping the data to the mappers and reducers. And I am not sure how does hadoop handles piping multiple args to a script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. Could you clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Say, if I have a script which looks like this:

arg1=$1;
arg2=$2;
do_something $arg1 $arg2;


Now, how'd I run this script using hadoop-streaming.

Comment: In that case, you may want to look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509063/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-python-hadoop-streaming-job?rq=1

Comment: I'd try that but I feel that this would work only if the parameters are constant or reside in the local file-system. In my case, arg1 and arg2 are names of the files in HDFS, and I have to somehow specify the inputs through -input arg and make hadoop streaming to consider both the args for a single execution of the script.

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to use multiple input files from HDFS in a streaming job? By default, hadoop processes all input together, it doesn't split separate -input statements into separate jobs. Just use multiple `-input` statements. You can refer to http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.22.0/streaming.html#How+do+I+specify+multiple+input+directories%3F as well.