# passing JSON argument as a string to python hadoop streaming application

Tags: python, json, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I want to pass a JSON string as command line argument to my reducer.py file but I'm unable to do so.

Command I execute is:

```
hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/hadoop/mapper.py -mapper 'mapper.py' -file /home/hadoop/reducer.py -reducer 'reducer.py {"abc":"123"}' -input /user/abc.txt -output /user/output/
```

When I print argv array in reducer.py, it shows output as:

```
['/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1423459215008_0057/container_1423459215008_0057_01_000004/./reducer.py', '{', 'abc', ':', '123', '}']
```

First argument is the path of reducer.py but my second argument gets split by double quotes.

I want to achieve second argument as a complete JSON string. For example like: `['/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1423459215008_0057/container_1423459215008_0057_01_000004/./reducer.py','{"abc":"123"}']`

So that I can load that argument as Json in reducer.py

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

EDIT:
Tried escaping JSON using command:

`hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/hadoop/mapper.py -mapper 'mapper.py' -file /home/hadoop/reducer.py -reducer 'reducer.py "{\"abc\":\"123\"}"' -input /user/abc.txt -output /user/output/`

Gives output as:

`['/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1423459215008_0058/container_1423459215008_0058_01_000004/./redu.py', '{\\', 'abc\\', ':\\', '123\\', '}']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your json inside double quotes with proper escaping: `"{\"abc\":\"123\"}"` but chances are that your input will be processed Hadoop before being passed to your script.

If this doesn't work you can try passing your arguments via environment with `-cmdenv name=value`. See [How do I pass a parameter to a python Hadoop streaming job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509063/how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-python-hadoop-streaming-job) for more details.

Comment: This might not work. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438852/pass-in-string-as-argument-without-it-being-treated-as-raw)

Comment: @frgtn Sadly it didnt work. It gives output as `['{\\', 'abc\\', ':\\', '123\\', '}']`

Comment: @shahsank3t can you update your question with full escaped input and output?

Comment: @frgtn I have noticed some weird thing after testing. It works if I do `'{\"gme\"}'` but it doesn't work if I do `"{\"gme\"}"`

Comment: @khajvah I've tested this by invoking script via shell. Hadoop may be processing the commands.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've used `-cmdenv name=value` and it worked for me. Thanks guys.